# Strange behavior with std::find_if()

Tags: c++

`std::find_if()` produces the wrong solution when used like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Node
{
    std::vector<int> mValues;
public:
    Node (std::vector<int> values) { mValues = values; }
    std::vector<int> getValues() { return mValues; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a= {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Node node(a);
    if (std::find_if(node.getValues().begin(), node.getValues().end(), [](int i) { return i == ((9)); }) != node.getValues().end())
    {
        std::cout << "FOUND " ;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND " ;
    }
}
```

The above code produces `Found`.

However, changing the `find_if()` to be like this instead:

```cpp
auto vec = node.getValues();
if (std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int i) { return i == ((9)); }) != vec.end())
```

This produces `Not Found`.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: In your constructor of Node you have `mvalues (vales)`. Is vales a typo?

Comment: For sure a Typo ,I corrected it

Comment: Also, I think you mean mvalues and not mavlues

Comment: The code shown does not compile, `node.mavlues` and `mvalues` mismatch. And `find_if` takes a `UnaryPredicate` as third argument and not a value.

Comment: Sorry , I edited it again with the correct syntax

Comment: Please provide a [mre], something that can be directly copy pasted and compiled with no modification whatsoever (fixing syntax errors, concatenating multiple code blocks, adding `#include`s, etc.)

Comment: `getValues` returns copies of the vectors, so you are finding in two disjoint unrelated vectors.

Comment: Doesnot the copy of the vector contains the same values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterators supplied to `find_if` in your code is invalid. The iterators supplied to `find_if` do not refer to the same container. Each time you call `get_values()` it returns a **copy** of the `std::vector<int>`, so a new, different container. Comparing two iterators that do not refer to the same container is undefined behavior. Your code invokes undefined behavior. Basically what you are doing is that:

```
int main() {
   std::vector<int> a;
   std::vector<int> b;
   std::vector<int> c;
   std::find_if(a.begin(), b.end(), something) != c.end();
}
```

The simplest fix it return a reference to the vector from `get_values()`:

```
std::vector<int>& getValues() {
   return mValues;
}
```

> What is the reason behind that ?

In the second code there is a single container `vec` and all iterators you use refer to the same container, so the code is valid.

Please indent your code to make it readable.

Comment: That makes a perfect sense , Thank you very much 